# Silverstripe 3 leftjoin

Tags: content-management-system, silverstripe

I have problems doing a leftjoin on a Custom Page Type "ProjectPage" and a corresponding relation table ("ProjectPage_Categories").
ProjectPage has many Categories and on Category can belong to many Projects.
ProjectPage looks like this:

```
class ProjectPage extends Page { 
    static $many_many = array(
        'Categories' => 'Category'
    );
```

and Category like that:

```
class Category extends DataObject {
    static $belongs_many_many = array(
        'ProjectPages' => 'ProjectPage'
    );
```

I´m trying to get all ProjectPages that are related to a certain category like this:

```
$projectPages = ProjectPage::get()
        ->leftJoin("ProjectPage_Categories", "ProjectPage_Categories.ProjectPageID = ProjectPage.ID")
        ->filter(array('CategoryID' => $categoryID));
```

unfortunately this does not work. there is always an sql error: *Unknown column 'ProjectPage.ID' in 'on clause'*

a very similar thing works without problems:

```
$members = Member::get()
    ->leftJoin("Group_Members", "Group_Members.MemberID = Member.ID")
    ->filter(array('GroupID' => '2'));
```

I´m guessing there is a problem because ProjectPage extends Sitetree and there is no table named "ProjectPage". I was trying to replace ProjectPage with SiteTree, but so far no success.

Many thanks,
Florian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if i'm getting it right you shouldn't need the manual join at all:

```
$category = Category::get()->byID($categoryID);
$projectPages = $category->ProjectPages();
```

no?

Comment: thank you, thats way to easy actually :) but here really hard to find: http://doc.silverstripe.org/framework/en/topics/datamodel I asked to add some lines about accessing relations.